# Bass identification

Tags: electric-bass-guitar

I got a bass from a friend of mine and would love to know the exact model of it. All I know is, that it is an Aria Bass and that I can't find this model on their homepage. Maybe someone can help me with this.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This one was quite identical to the one you posted:* [ARIA PRO II IGB-49 Integra Bass](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ARIA-PRO-II-IGB-49-Integra-Bass-USED-FREE-SHIPPING-from-Japan-/282026556116)

[image]